# getting import error, DLL file load failed, having python3.7 , installed tensorflow and keras, still the same errror

Tags: pip, python-3.7, tensorflow2.0, importerror, keras-2

C:\Users\Raj Kubal>python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Raj Kubal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Raj Kubal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Raj Kubal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Users\Raj Kubal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
  File "C:\Users\Raj Kubal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Raj Kubal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 83, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Raj Kubal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: Is your environment activated? Are you installing `tensorflow` on that activated virtual environment itself? How are you installing it? Using `pip`? Please elaborate your issue in a good way.

Comment: Sorry for inconvinience...since im new,................i opened cmd directly and the entered the following code ...can u pls tell me how to activate environment as i just bfore i tried to force reinstall it.................i have jupyter notebook installed.

Comment: Force installing gave me this error

Comment: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\users\\raj kubal\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\~-mpy\\.libs\\libopenblas.PYQHXLVVQ7VESDPUVUADXEVJOBGHJPAY.gfortran-win_amd64.dll'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Try `python -m pip install tensorflow`

Comment: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.                                                                        still the same

Comment: if i say pip uninstall tensorflow its shows the modules presence

Comment: You need to direct to the directoy path of your python installation. If it's in virtual environment then do it from there.

Comment: ok ill try and let uk